# Creating an npm module with target specific code

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules

I am currently working on a javascript module that includes code for both web and nodejs targets. These are each in their separate files (index.node.js and index.web.js), and I want the runtime/compiler to select which one it needs based on which target it is currently working for. So node should automatically pick up index.node.js when "require"-ing the module, whilst webpack, when building for the web target, should automatically go for the index.web.js file.

However, just relying on the extension to get this done doesn't work, as it then complains about missing index.js. How can one go about implementing this in a way that webpack really only includes one of the files (so no runtime overhead), and that it actually just works without effort on the end users side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats what the fields `browser` and `main` can be used for:

```
{
  "browser": "index.web.js" 
  "main": "index.node.js"
}
```

Webpack uses the browser field as default. Node uses the main field (as far as I remember).

When compiling with Webpack for the backend (yes - this is a thing) - the user would need to change [the target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) and probably change [how modules are resolved](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).